# Why is Debian 9 switching active nics on reboot?

Tags: nic, debian-stretch

I have been using Debian for years in a production environment. Installations changing from Jessy to Stretch I have noticed that now the NIC's take on non traditional names. They are no longer eth0, eth1, etc. I get that and can live with that.

What I have issue with is sometimes the NIC's are simply named 'rename'. The last two servers I did one server has 2 NIC's, one named eno1 and the other is simply 'rename3'. The other server also has two NIC's and they are named rename2, and rename3.

What's worse and probably the most important issue. Upon rebooting, the active NIC switches to the other. If I restart a server remotely I will physically need to go onsite and pull the Ethernet cable from one port and put it in the other port.

This is not good. I have done many searches, but all I can find is info on why the naming of NIC's has changed and how to rename them back to ethx.

What am I missing? What steps do I need to include on server builds to prevent the NIC's from swapping which is active on reboot?

Thank you.

As requested...
roleme@galadriel:~$ uname -a
Linux galadriel 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

On my Stretch I added a MAC -> interface name mapping using the `/lib/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules` file.

Example `/lib/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="00:1d:72:94:9c:0a", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="d4:9a:20:5d:7f:0b", NAME="eth1"
```

Replace the MAC addresses with yours and give it a try.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I was hoping someone had an answer as to why this occurs.